# Xamarin forms and Firebase AdMob for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, admob, xamarin.forms, renderer

Until few days ago, my apps were working fine until I received a message in the *Output* where it advises me to add the following line:

```
request.TestDevices = new[] { "yourtestcodeid" };
```

For the Xamarin Components Store, the component called *Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds* doesn't exists any more but you have to install *Firebase AdMob for iOS*.

The problem is that the example is only for a natve iOS project. I've a Xamarin forms project with a generic view in the main project

```
public class AdMobView : ContentView {
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AdMobView"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public AdMobView() {
    }
}
```

and in the project for each platform its implementation. For iOS was:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdMobView), typeof(AdMobRenderer))]
namespace WordBankEasy.iOS.Renderers {
public class AdMobRenderer : ViewRenderer {
    const string AdmobID = "ca-app-pub-yourcode";

    BannerView adView;
    BannerView adViewTableView;
    BannerView adViewWindow;
    Interstitial adInterstitial;
    bool viewOnScreen;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e) {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(e.NewElement == null)
            return;

        if(e.OldElement == null)
        {
            adView = new BannerView(
                size: AdSizeCons.SmartBannerPortrait, 
                origin: new CGPoint(0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Height - AdSizeCons.Banner.Size.Height))
            {
                AdUnitID = AdmobID,
                RootViewController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController
            };

            adView.AdReceived += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if(!viewOnScreen) this.AddSubview(adView);
                viewOnScreen = true;
            };

            adView.LoadRequest(GetRequest());
            base.SetNativeControl(adView);
        }
    }

    private void AdViewWindow_AdReceived(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    Request GetRequest()
    {
        var request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();
        // Requests test ads on devices you specify. Your test device ID is printed to the console when
        // an ad request is made. GADBannerView automatically returns test ads when running on a
        // simulator. After you get your device ID, add it here
        request.TestDevices = new[] { "96080e40efec5229aad21b540eae6fe0" };
        return request;
    }
}
}
```

Now I can't view an ads but I have a new kind of error

> You must set the rootViewController property of <GADBannerView: 0x12de69c50; frame = (0 617; 375 50); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x17103da00>> before loading a request.

How can I change my code? Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new component there is a little change to do in the code like that:

```
if(e.OldElement == null)
{
    UIViewController viewCtrl = null;

    foreach(UIWindow v in UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows)
    {
        if (v.RootViewController != null)
        {
            viewCtrl = v.RootViewController;
        }
    }

    adView = new BannerView(size: AdSizeCons.Banner, origin: new CGPoint(-10, 0))
    {
        AdUnitID = AdmobID,
        RootViewController = viewCtrl
    };

    adView.AdReceived += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if(!viewOnScreen) this.AddSubview(adView);
        viewOnScreen = true;
    };

    adView.LoadRequest(GetRequest());
    base.SetNativeControl(adView);
}
```